# I have a dropzone with dropzone.js but it s not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dropzone.js

I am using adminlte.io for my admin panel. Users can add image multiple. I am using dropzone.js . In desktop no problem, but in mobile phone form exist any class like dropzone. Please help me, i need really help

I dont know anything to do something

```
    <form id="myAwesomeDropzone" class="dropzone" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('panel/resimyukleduzenle/').$this->uri->segment(3); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<div class="dz-message needsclick">
Resimleri taşıyarak veya seçerek yükleyebilirsiniz.<br>
```

This is my view. It's work perfectly desktop but on mobile phone  tag 
is not exist class and it crashing